# Лексические ошибки

Tags: лексика

1. Главное разведывательное управление направило в столицу Великобритании своего диссидента.
2. В составах команд немало именитых спортсменов, не раз добившихся отменных результатов в соревнованиях.
3. Художник писал свои акварели масляными красками, приготовленными по особому рецепту.

Comment: >Главное разведывательное управление направило в столицу Великобритании своего диссидента.  
  
Это пять! Можно украсть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Главное разведывательное управление направило в столицу Великобритании своего диссидента (резидента).
2. В составах команд немало именитых спортсменов, не раз добившихся отменных (отличных) результатов в соревнованиях.
3. Художник писал свои акварели масляными (акварель - это живопись водяными красками, поэтому "масляными" неправильно, это слово надо убрать) красками, приготовленными по особому рецепту.